# iOS like coordinate-system in Mac app

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, coordinates, coordinate-systems

I just started with my first Mac App, but I realised that the coordinate-system is "flipped" (x = 0, y = 0 is in the lower left corner). I'm having a lot of trouble with UI programming because I'm used to the iOS coordinate-system.

**My Question now is:**
Can I flip the coordinate-system of my App/Window forever so that I don't have to flip all my subviews also.

**Thats my App:**
My apps window contains a NSScrollView with posts from recent to old. When I add my first post I want it to be right at the top of the scrollView.

I hope someone had the same problem and can help me out.
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can do a override of the method called `- (BOOL)isFlipped` in your NSView classes. Make it to return `YES` to get the iOS like coordinate system(AKA flipped). By default it returns NO, just like what you see now. Do so will also solve your second problem because the coordinates are flipped.

Comment: I tried that before. But it doesn't work. 
I subclassed a NSView and took my windows contentView and made it a a FlippedView. 
I asume that's what you mean.
But when I add a new view to this flipped view the coordinate-system of the new view is not flipped (back to the normal mac coordinate-system)

Comment: Setting geometryflipped = true on the Layer worked fine for me with Xamarin OSX as IsFlipped was made a read only property.

Answer (score 1):

you can change it programatically as TonyD has suggested or via interface builder in size inspector using origin pane

[image: origin]